# Menu Bar and Launcher Missing in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: unity, 14.04, compiz, launcher

After a restart my menu bar and launcher were missing. I have tried every solution for this issue that I can find, from re-installing `unity` and `compiz` to resetting Unity and everything.

Then I decided to reinstall Ubuntu 14.04 without formatting and still had the same problem.

When I run unity I get `Error: Plugin 'opengl' not loaded.`

What can I do?

Comment: Probably relevant: http://askubuntu.com/questions/17381/unity-doesnt-load-no-launcher-no-dash-appears

Answer (score 1):

first run

```
dpkg -l | grep opengl
```

This will tell you what opengl accelerators are installed on your system.

To search available packages, the following . . .

```
apt-cache search openGL | grep plugin
```

. . . results in a few interesting results.

Notably,

**compiz-plugins-default - OpenGL window and compositing manager - default plugins**
**compiz-plugins - OpenGL window and compositing manager - plugins**

Try running

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall compiz-plugins-default compiz-plugins compiz-plugins-extra compiz-plugins-main compiz-plugins-main-default compizconfig-settings-manager
```