# menu and sidebar disappeared ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, unity, launcher

I'm having a weird problem, every time I've restart my ubuntu session the menu bar and the sidebar disappear after some time, (sometimes more sometimes less)

I've tried many solutions found over there but the problem still remains. 
Solutions testes: 
-Reinstalling compiz [Solution](https://askubuntu.com/questions/506071/menu-bar-and-launcher-missing-in-ubuntu-14-04)

-Reinstalling unity and ubuntu-desktop

I don't really know what's going on, but every time I restart the session it appears again and disappears after some time.

Some clue of why this could happen and some other solutions??

Thanx!!!

Comment: sorry but i tryed that solution too and it didn,t work

Comment: Something that you could try: create a new user and log in with that user. If the problem persists, the issue is most likely in the system settings; however, if the problem disappears, then some file(s) in your regular user's home directory tree are more likely to be the culprit.

(Of course, if you re-installed in such a fashion that your home directory was emptied while installing, then it is very likely that the source of the problem is in the system settings, or even a bug.)

Comment: I updated to ubuntu 16.04 and I reinstalled deleting all the old files and the problem still remains, can be something worst, and be some damage in disk, how to check this??